# I think "Thank you for letting me knows" is incorrect. Am I right?

Tags: spelling, error

Microsoft Word corrected my text to read

> Thank you for letting me knows

so now I'm a little unsure that *know* is correct and *knows* is incorrect.

I usually work it out by the ‘which sounds right’ method.
And the phrase "Thank you for letting me knows" just sounds wrong.
Shouldn't it be "Thank you for letting me know"?

What am I missing here?

Comment: I've just tried it in word and you are right. What on Earth is MS Word thinking, beats me... But the sentence "Thank you for letting me **know**" is definitely the correct one ('know' is a bare infinitive here). What is fascinating is that when you write "Let me know" is doesn't change it. "Letting me know about this was a huge favour" also isn't marked as incorrect. It's just after "thank you for..." Really strange... Word is definitely wrong here. Computers just aren't perfect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about a software but.

Comment: @Chenmunka I disagree. It's a question about English that arose from a software bug.

Comment: I agree with @DJMcMayhem This is not a question about a software bug, it is a question about English.  If this gets closed as off-topic because it is about a software bug, then questions that say something like "I think it's this and my friend thinks it's that" would have to be closed as relationship questions.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, "Thank you for letting me know." is correct. "Know" in that sentence should be an infinitive (without 'to') and not conjugated, which MS Word did.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, the problem is about "know" or "knows". There are several verbs which follow  the same type of construction, for example: (let; make; have  + somebody + Base Form (not conjugated verb) + (something) e.g. let-permission- (my parents let me arrive late); make- by force (she has made me eat everything); have- common request + (His boss had him type five letters this morning.)

Regarding "for letting", due to the fact that *letting* is preceded by a preposition (in this case, **FOR**, - after a preposition, follows an -ing verb).

Comment: That said, *make* requires *to-infinitive* when passivized: e.g., *He was made to repeat what he said*.

Comment: @user178049 Why did you delete [this post?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/142139/grammatical-explanation-of-a-sentence-that-begins-with-there)

Comment: @Araucaria I wasn't sure if it was actually correct. If you think it's correct, I would undelete :)

Comment: @user178049 Looks correct to me!